octet-stream data parsing in Apache Nifi
I have an octet-stream data generate from ListenHTTP procecssor. I want to transform/convert this octet-stream data into text or JSON application. ListenHTTP
The octet-stream data is like
0x00000000  0A  AD  02  0A  8E  01  0A  20  0A  0C  73  65  72  76  69  63  ....... ..servic
0x00000010  65  2E  6E  61  6D  65  12  10  0A  0E  43  61  6C  6C  65  72  e.name....Caller
0x00000020  2D  73  65  72  76  69  63  65  0A  20  0A  16  74  65  6C  65  -service. ..tele
0x00000030  6D  65  74  72  79  2E  73  64  6B  2E  6C  61  6E  67  75  61  metry.sdk.langua
0x00000040  67  65  12  06  0A  04  6A  61  76  61  0A  25  0A  12  74  65  ge....java.%..te
0x00000050  6C  65  6D  65  74  72  79  2E  73  64  6B  2E  6E  61  6D  65  lemetry.sdk.name
0x00000060  12  0F  0A  0D  6F  70  65  6E  74  65  6C  65  6D  65  74  72  ....opentelemetr
0x00000070  79  0A  21  0A  15  74  65  6C  65  6D  65  74  72  79  2E  73  y.!..telemetry.s
0x00000080  64  6B  2E  76  65  72  73  69  6F  6E  12  08  0A  06  31  2E  dk.version....1.
0x00000090  33  38  2E  30  12  99  01  0A  3B  0A  1A  69  6E  73  74  72  38.0....;..instr
0x000000A0  75  6D  65  6E  74  61  74  69  6F  6E  2D  73  63  6F  70  65  umentation-scope
0x000000B0  2D  6E  61  6D  65  12  1D  69  6E  73  74  72  75  6D  65  6E  -name..instrumen
0x000000C0  74  61  74  69  6F  6E  2D  73  63  6F  70  65  2D  76  65  72  tation-scope-ver
0x000000D0  73  69  6F  6E  12  5A  0A  10  37  5C  89  1E  49  07  CE  C4  sion.Z..7\..I...
0x000000E0  02  07  AA  87  C8  0D  7B  69  12  08  D3  C0  79  29  9A  E7  ......{i....y)..
0x000000F0  C7  E4  22  00  2A  0A  70  72  6F  63  65  73  73  69  6E  67  ..".*.processing
0x00000100  30  01  39  F8  9E  7D  94  48  C2  D9  17  41  F0  C4  CD  94  0.9..}.H...A....
0x00000110  48  C2  D9  17  4A  18  0A  0E  49  73  42  75  73  69  6E  65  H...J...IsBusine
0x00000120  73  73  53  70  61  6E  12  06  0A  04  74  72  75  65  7A  00  ssSpan....truez.
0x00000130  10

I have tried various processors like ConvertRecord, ConvertCharaterSet but I'm not able to get which is the type which I need to select for the incoming octet-data. ConvertCharaterSet configuration. ConvertRecord configuration

it's not a json. sounds like it's a binary telemetry message. you can try to use ListenOTLP instead of ListenHTTP (not sure it will help). The right way to ask/configure the message producer to change format of message to json. if it's not an option - ask them the specification of the binary message they are using. to convert binary message to json you have to write a custom code or use a library (but you need to know the format). just to give you an idea what it could be: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-metric-streams-formats-opentelemetry-parse.html
